# Can someone share nginx config for reverse proxying Kibana 5.1.1

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, kibana-5

I am newbie to Nginx and reverse proxy

I am struggling to make accessing of kibana through Nginx work with latest versions of Kibana Kibana 5.1.1

This is current config

```
server {
        listen      8070;

    location ~ /analytics/(?<kibana_uri>.*) {
        proxy_pass https://stag.xxxxx.xxxx.es.amazonaws.com:5601/$kibana_uri;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    }
```

server.basepath : "/analytics"

I want to redirect all request for /analytics to my kibana server instance. but all I am getting is 404.Please help me with some example config if anyone has done it earlier.

And how should be the access link
For eg: http://localhost:8070/analytics